CORS error when fetching from external API
I am trying to fetch from an external API, and I am getting CORS error.
Where can I add the domain to allow the fetch?

To a proxy server maybe, that makes the request for you? cors is typically handled by the server serving the api. It's likely you aren't meant to use this api from the browser, or some error is occuring and the API's error response doesn't send cors headers.
